# getting the value of file input type returns empty - angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get the value of file input type in angular using the id. I am able to get the file name but when I try to get the value of the input, it returns empty and throws error in the code.

here is my code

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file"
                             id="doc" size="60"/>
```

ts file where I am attempting to get the value

```
let f = (document.getElementById('doc') as HTMLInputElement).files[0]
      let formdataF = (document.getElementById('doc') as HTMLInputElement).value

      console.log("document name " + JSON.stringify(f)); //this keeps returning empty
```

kindly assist

Comment: At what point are you doing this?

Comment: upon selecting the upload button from the view

Comment: So does this `(document.getElementById('doc') as HTMLInputElement).value` get you the correct value?

Comment: yes. let me attach my header codes

Comment: weird but the truth, my header was the problem. Thanks a million, your insights led me to the solution, to where I never thought that could be the problem

Comment: :D Good that you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't convert Object File to JSON string with stringify.

What you can do is :

1. Reading the file as string :

Example :

```
async getValues() {
  let f = (document.getElementById('doc') as HTMLInputElement).files[0]
  let formdataF = (document.getElementById('doc') as HTMLInputElement).value
  const toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });
  const result = await toBase64(f);
  console.log("file", JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

2. Reading the file as **base64** string :

Example :

```
getValues() {
  let f = (document.getElementById('doc') as HTMLInputElement).files[0]
  let formdataF = (document.getElementById('doc') as HTMLInputElement).value
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        console.log('file :', event.target.result);
    };
  reader.readAsText(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my personal Experience, below  code will work

```
var input = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('file');
```

console.log(input.files.item(0).name)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).